# Why two css matrix3d transformation gets different result?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, homography

I want to transform svg from square to trapezoid.

I implemented the conversion in two ways with reference to [this site](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/10571478).
One is the transformation in the svg tag, the other is in the g tag.
When transformed with the svg tag, the expected result was obtained.
However, when it was transformed in the g tag, it could not be transformed well.

What is the difference between the two codes?
How can I fix it to make the desired transformation in the g tag?

```html
<svg id="transform" width="100" height="100" overflow="visible"
     style="transform-origin: 100px 100px 0px; transform: matrix3d(1.00917, 0, 0, 9.2e-05, 0, 0.908257, 0, -0.000917, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);">
  <g transform="translate(100,100)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="blue"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>

<svg id="transform2" width="100" height="100" overflow="visible">
  <g id="upper"
     style="transform-origin: 100px 100px 0px; transform: matrix3d(1.00917, 0, 0, 9.2e-05, 0, 0.908257, 0, -0.000917, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);">
    <g transform="translate(100,100)">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="red"></rect>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The source code and demo are here https://codepen.io/fbkclanna/pen/LYYEPJo.

I want the red square to be transformed in the same way as the blue square.

Comment: As far as I know only Firefox supports 3d transforms of general SVG elements other than the outer <svg> element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I only tried it on Google Chrome and Safari. Firefox displayed the ideal result. Thank you.